# How to build a rules table in sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2016

There are quite a few business rules which are currently hardcoded within a stored procedure. Wanted to explore the option of setting up a rules table where in we intend to key-in all business rules and based on it execute the stored procedure.

Though the system is little complicated have provided a simple version here.

```
Create table tblTest
(
    TranID int primary key not null,
    FName varchar(20) not null,
    Age int not null,
    Salary money not null,
    MaritalStatus char(1) not null
)

Insert into tblTest values (1, 'Alex', 26, '25000.00','Y')
Insert into tblTest values (2, 'Brenda', 25, '14500.00','Y')
Insert into tblTest values (3, 'Peter', 69, '50000.00','N')
Insert into tblTest values (4, 'Paul', 64, '74500.00','Y')
```

Now to keep the example simple lets assume the business rules to be the following:
1. Age >=25,
2. Age < 65 and
3. Salary > 15K

```
Create table tblBusRule
(
    RuleID int Primary key not null,
    ColName varchar(20) not null,
    Operator varchar(2) not null,
    ColValue varchar(10) not null,
    RuleOrder int not null
)

Insert into tblBusRule values (1, 'Age', '>=', '25', 1)
Insert into tblBusRule values (2, 'Age', '<', '65', 2)
Insert into tblBusRule values (3, 'Salary', '>', '15000.00', 3)
```

The direct query would be something like this which would output the record 1 (Alex) and 4 (Paul) alone.

```
Select * from tblTest
where 
        age >=25 and 
        age < 65 and 
        salary > '15000.00'
```

Now how to make this dynamic based on the rules mentioned in tblBusRule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [**`stuff()`** with **`select ... for xml path ('')`** method of string concatenation](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/) and [**`sp_executesql`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql)

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max), @where nvarchar(max);
set @where = stuff((
  select '  and '+colname +' '+operator +' ' + colvalue+char(10)
    from tblBusRule
    order by RuleOrder
  for xml path (''), type).value('.','nvarchar(max)')
  ,1,6,'');

set @sql = 'select * ' +char(10)+'from tblTest'+char(10)+'where '+@where;

select @sql as CodeGenerated;
exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/CGRF91788

returns:

```
+-------------------------+
|      CodeGenerated      |
+-------------------------+
| select *                |
| from tblTest            |
| where Age >= 25         |
|   and Age < 65          |
|   and Salary > 15000.00 |
+-------------------------+

+--------+-------+-----+------------+---------------+
| TranID | FName | Age |   Salary   | MaritalStatus |
+--------+-------+-----+------------+---------------+
|      1 | Alex  |  26 | 25000,0000 | Y             |
|      4 | Paul  |  64 | 74500,0000 | Y             |
+--------+-------+-----+------------+---------------+
```

Reference: 
- [The curse and blessings of dynamic SQL - Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just trying to understand how flexible can we make this business rule table. In case if a rule has to be applied against a different table how would the script change. I mean assume salary column is in TableB.

Comment: @prasanth . . . well it can be as flexible as the amount of work you put into it... If you wanted to have the rules apply to multiple tables, then you should probably identify which rules apply to which tables, and retrieve rules that apply to the tables in your query.

Comment: :) Ok maybe will post it as a separate question with sample structure and output expected to get more clarity. Thanks.